# Data filtering with kafka and mysql

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I receive data in following format:

> msg1:

```
{
  "A" : null,
  "B" : 123,
  "C" : {...}
}
```

> msg2:

```
{
  "A" : 456,
  "B" : null,
  "C" : {...}
}
```

The data is not partitioned and it is delivered randomly to all 20 partitions in topic.

Now, I need to create a filtering app, that will take this data, filter it based on some rules and data from MySQL database and forward to other kafka topic. First, I need to fill in missing data based on MySQL database data (for msg1 it will make `{"A": 100, "B": 123}` and for msg2 `{"A": 456, "B": 200}` - so it takes values `100` and `200` from MySQL database). It then needs to determine if message with same "A" field was forwarded in last 30 seconds - if it is it should reject it and if not, it will forward to next topic.

Currently, the best way that I can think here is to ingest MySQL data with Debezium, and using log compaction always to have current snapshot of data on some topic - and this topic should probably be `GlobalTable` that I can later use with Kafka Streams `KStream` to do the joining and windowed aggregation.

Is there any other easier/performant way?

Comment: Does the receiving data come from the Kafka? How do you fill the missing data according to MySQL database? Based on which field? You want reject messages which have been forwarded in the past 30 seconds. I think you can cache the key field of message in Redis. You can look up redis cache before sending to the sink Kafka topic.

Comment: Yes, it comes from Kafka. In mysql database, I just find records by one of the candidate keys (e.g. in DB I have records A=100,B=123 and A=456,B=200 so I can find it in db for msg1 by key B and for msg2 by key A). Would redis be faster or it would be faster if data was already in the kafka?

Comment: Kafka Streams cannot easily select on multiple, arbitrary fields. Redis probably would be faster, but it's unclear what your keys look like